# When a line item is removed from an order, is it ok to have a transaction across bounded contexts?

Tags: domain-driven-design, bounded-contexts

In my domain, I have 2 bounded contexts that are relevant to this question:

1. Purchasing - where the customer orders services
2. Fulfillment - where services are assigned to vendors to be completed

It's a requirement that an order is editable by the customer at any given time throughout the life of the order.

If a customer removes a service from an order (i.e. within the purchasing context), if that service has already been assigned to a vendor to be performed (but has not already been performed) that service must also be removed in the fulfillment context.

There's a couple of options here, and I'd like the community's opinion:

1. I have my contexts wrong because this will create a cross-context transaction.
2. I may not need transactional consistency here.  Of course, that's for the business stakeholder to decide, which begs 2 questions:  What are the implementation options?  How do I pose this question to the business stakeholder?
3. This is an acceptable violation of the "no cross-context transactions" rule.

**EDIT**

This is all happening within a single process, so the likelihood of mid-transaction failure is very low.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the question to ask your stakeholder, re: an order being editable at all times - what does it mean for an order to be edited after it has already been fulfilled?

Comment: I didn't make this clear.  The service has not been fulfilled.  It's just been scheduled with a vendor and the vendor will need to be updated (that is, issued a new statement of work) reflecting the removed service.

Comment: I updated the text of the question to reflect my comment above.  And thank, Udi!

Answer (score 0):

Why is it necessary that when an order is edited, this impacts the fulfillment service?

This, in my mind, crosses the bounded contexts. An order, while being edited, should not leave its domain unless there is good reason to. Why would any order information be propagated to the fulfillment service before it is complete?

Based on my obviously very limited understanding of your domain, I would think that you would complete the order first, then send a creation event to the service bus, where it is picked up by the fulfillment service. Therefore, no transactions are taking place that cross contexts.

Comment: Orders are editable until the services have actually been performed.  I know it's weird, but it's a requirement of the domain.  These orders are complex and things are being added (and possibly removed, which is my main concern because performing a service that the customer wanted to cancel costs the stakeholders money).

Comment: I think in your scenario, having things run inside a transaction is impossible because there are operations taking place over a certain period of time, including cancelling operations (adding an order line, removing it again). I think the only way to implement this properly is by means of events per operation (OrderLineAdded, OrderLineRemoved) and the corresponding event handlers. That means compensation rather than transaction, I'm afraid. Just my 2 cents.